# Filling list containing words using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is my list:

```
List<ActionType> actionTypeList = new ActionTypeLogic(ApplicationType.Web).GetAllActionTypes();
```

I want to fill a dropdown list by its items where `actionTypeList` has a word (complete, new, still) only using Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
string[] words = new[] {"complete", "new", "still"};
actionTypeList.Where(x => words.Contains(x.Word)).ForEach(x => myDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(x.Word, x.Value)));
```

[List.ForEach method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not really LINQ, yet it fits in this scenario.

Otherwise I kindly ask you to specify your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 new ActionTypeLogic(ApplicationType.Web).GetAllActionTypes().Select(x => x.MyWord).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this :

```
string[] words = new []{"new", "complete", "still"}; 
dropDownList.DataSource = actionTypeList.Where(at=>words.Contains(at.SomeField)).Select(at=> new {at.SomeField, at.SomeOtherField});
dropDownList.DataTextField = "some title for first field";
dropDownList.DataValueField = "some title for second field";
dropDownList.DataBind();
```